# How to merge dataframes when there are duplicates

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to merge two datasets:

data_a

```
 group |  x  |  y 
  101  |  1  |  test
  101  |  1  |  one
  102  |  7  |  two
  102  |  3  |  three
```

data_b

```
 group |  z  | 
  101  |  1  | 
  102  |  3  |
```

I want to merge data_a into data_b when group = group and x = z. However, sometimes there are duplicate occurrences where there are two rows in data_a that get merged. Instead, I'd like to only merge the first occurrence if possible:

data_b

```
 group |  z  | y
  101  |  1  | test
  102  |  3  | three
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using data from [G. Grothendieck](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45725065/7128934)

```
data_b$y = data_a$y[match(paste(data_b$group, data_b$z), paste(data_a$group, data_a$x))]
data_b
#  group z     y
#1   101 1  test
#2   102 3 three
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it using `dplyr`. `slice(1)` keeps the first row per group of group and x, and then you perform an inner join.

```
library(dplyr)
data_a %>% group_by(group,x) %>% slice(1) %>% inner_join(data_b,by=c("group"="group","x"="z"))
  group     x      y
  <int> <int> <fctr>
1   101     1   test
2   102     3  three
```

Comment: @NBC could you describe how this solution doesn't work? Could you simply try it out first?

Comment: If you only keep the first row per group, then you may unintentionally cut out a row that should be matched (row 4 of the first dataframe)

Comment: You group per group and x, not just per group, so slice doesn't cut out the fourth row, only the second row.

Answer (score -1):

First extract the first row among each set of rows of data_a having the same group and then merge that with data_b using the indicated join. No packages are used.

```
data_a_u <- data_a[!duplicated(data_a[1]), ]
merge(data_b, data_a_u, all.y = TRUE, by = 1:2)
```

giving:

```
  group z    y
1   101 1 test
2   102 7  two
```

**Note:** The input data in reproducible form is:

```
Lines_a <- "
group |  x  |  y 
  101  |  1  |  test
  101  |  1  |  one
  102  |  7  |  two
  102  |  3  |  three"
data_a <- read.table(text = Lines_a, header = TRUE, sep = "|", strip.white = TRUE)

Lines_b <- "
group |  z  | 
  101  |  1  | 
  102  |  3  |"
data_b <- read.table(text = Lines_b, header = TRUE, sep = "|", strip.white = TRUE)[1:2]
```

Comment: I edited my post - not sure that you can just look at the first row. Does my edit make sense?

Comment: The question is not clear what is means by "first row" but I have assumed that it means the first row of multiple rows in data_a having the same group value.and have changed code accordingly (previously I had interpreted it as havnig the same groupo and x).  Also modified data to correspond to changes in question

Comment: this is wrong. the output I want for the 2nd row is 102 | 3| three, instead yours ends with 2

Comment: Your description stated it wanted the first of duplicates and that is the second 102.